# Removing a PYGTK treeview row programmatically

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

I'm trying to find out how you remove a row in a pygtk treeview without selecting it. I can remove rows by selecting the row first but the application I'm working on needs to be able to remove rows automatically (without the user selecting the row). As simple a feature as this seems to be I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. I've trawled through the pygtk API and the web without success.

If anyone knows how to do this or have a link to a site that could give me a jump start on this issue, it would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the model underlying, and access any line by one of its three reference methods. Say iter is the row number :

```
 model = gtk.TreeView.get_model()
 model.remove(iter)
```

should do the trick.

But you will be better to work immediately on the listStore without passing by the treeview, it will be easier end faster.

Comment: This is it, though it should be noted that an iter will be an internal representation of a row, via poiter to memory, whereas a path will contain the row number. So if he knows the row number, the path will be the way to go. But, if he's dealing with removing items he'll need reference iters because paths and normal iters may become invalid after the contents of a tree model have been changed.  (just some extra details for @Chris Lamb)

Comment: Thank you Brandon, this is right. I was thinking accessing only the line (not the cell by referring line and column) so I did not went further. Indeed, when the content has changed, the line number (in the iterator) changes too.